# Open port 23 to read data using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, port, telnet, tcp

On my windows laptop there is a program with a TCP/IP server on port 23. I can open it with a telnet terminal and see the data streaming. I need to get that data into a node.js program I'm working on. Should be easy but I haven't found any code examples. Searches come up with lots of examples of how to make a server on port 23 with Node.js.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a high level TCP/IP socket implementation in node. See: [Node net API](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html)

```
var net = require('net'),
    port = 23, 
    host = 'localhost',
    socket = net.createConnection(port, host);

socket
  .on('data', function(data) {
          console.log('received: ' + data);
      })
  .on('connect', function() {
          console.log('connected');
      })
  .on('end', function() {
          console.log('closed');
      });
```

Comment: One more dumb question. Once the client is running, how do I stop it? Other that closing the console window?

Comment: `process.exit()` will cause your node app to end itself. To end it manually, use `Ctrl-C`.